# scp from linux to an external drive on mac

Tags: linux, macos, permissions, scp

I have been using the following command to copy between a linux machine and a mac and it works fine:

```
scp -r /home/ubuntu/Desktop/somefolder username@ipaddress:/Users/username/Documents/somefolder
```

But now I would like to copy over to an external drive on the mac and have tried the following:

```
scp -r /home/ubuntu/Desktop/somefolder username@ipaddress:/Volumes/MyDrive/somefolder
```

But it gives me Operation not permitted. I have macOS Big Sur and this must have something with permissions. When I created the somefolder folder on the external drive I was asked to approve it with a password.

Any idea how to get around this?

Btw the reason I am doing this and not connecting the external drive directly to the Linux machine, is that it has no working usb ports to connect an external drive to it.

Edit:
I changed the permissions on the external drive to read write for my user and also did the same for the Volumes folder. Now my user on the mac can create a folder without giving a password. But still no luck with the scp command.

Answer (score 5):

This fixed the problem:
Had to go to System Preferences on the mac and select:
Security & Privacy -> Privacy -> Full Disk Access
and tick the box in front of:

```
sshd-keygen-wrapper
```

Answer (score 5):

In `MacOS Monterey 12.6` go to settings of `System Preferences > Sharing > Remote Login` and enable enable the `[x] Allow full disk access for remote users`.

In my case it has affect on both SSH connection and SFTP.

Comment: And the same was required under macOS 13.3.1

Comment: It is in System Settings > General > Sharing Remote Login > (i) in macOS 14 (Sonoma).